# Simulation of multivariate time series data using r

Tags: r

I want to simulate a multivariate time series data which fits to the year given in the table. How can I do that?

I use the following code

```
Z <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1.5)

# process simulation
X <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Z)) {

# my table
my_table <- 1982:2008
```

Comment: I replaced your picture of the numbers from 1982 to 2008 with some code. Pictures of numbers (especially of a single sequence of numbers) usually aren't very helpful.

Comment: I'm also pretty unclear on your goals... What is `X`? Why do you make `Z` 100 random numbers, when your table is for 27 years? You say you want a *multivariate* time series, but you only generate a single variable `Z`... how many other variables do you want to generate? What is your expected output?

Comment: I think you may be right, but I want to create a multivariate time series data from year 1982:2008, at least 4 times as I have some data and developed some models on those years and I want to compare these models with the simulated data, so I have to simulate the data for given years equally with the original data. In the given code, I wanted to place the values in the "for loop" in the preallocated memory "x" but I couldn't go further on the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the covariance or correlation of series. If there is not correlation it would be easy.

```
# No correlation: 
my_table <- 1982:2008
num.series <- 4

sdata=matrix(rnorm(length(my_table)*num.series,0,sd=1.5),ncol=num.series)
sdf=data.frame(my_table,sdata)
summary(sdf)

# with covariance
library(MASS)
Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,3,3,5,3,3,3,3,8,3,3,3,3,15)/10,ncol=4)
Sigma
smdata=mvrnorm(n = length(my_table), rep(0, num.series), Sigma)
scdf=data.frame(my_table,smdata)
summary(scdf)
```

Comment: What do you think if there is a correlation? or any general idea that I will be working on it if there is a correlation?

Comment: If you have historical data you could compute covariance and correlations and see if those are significant, or maybe there is some theory that you can use.